# socket.io Rooms Connection Limitation

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have question about `socket.io`.

Is there a way to limit connections in rooms? I want to limit connections room to two users.

So that only the employer and the designer can talk.

Answer (score 1):

use this code and limit the user to join. I think this is the simplest way possible --->>>

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("User Connected :" + socket.id);

  //Triggered when a peer hits the join room button.

  socket.on("join", function (roomName) {
    let rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
    let room = rooms.get(roomName);

    //room == undefined when no such room exists.

    if (room == undefined) {
      socket.join(roomName);
      socket.emit("created");
    } else if (room.size == 1) {
      //room.size == 1 when one person is inside the room.
      socket.join(roomName);
      socket.emit("joined");
    } else {
      //when there are already two people inside the room.
      socket.emit("full");
    }
    console.log(rooms);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need some sort of identifier. If you have their username, you can just search for their username in some sort of Map containing username to the respective socket. Then, when you send a message you can use `socket.to(anothersocket.id).emit("message", "message content)`. The other person will message to your socket.id. This is because all sockets are in the room of their id.